# What happens if I don't have Linux drivers for my laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, but I did not get any drivers for Ubuntu 11.10 for that laptop.

When I had installed Windows 7, the performance was not optimal without the drivers.

What happens in Ubuntu 11.10 if I don't have the drivers?

Comment: Ubuntu provides all drivers. Do you experience any problem?

Comment: yes,it is about battery notification, VGA is not detected, and screen brightness

Comment: Well you already asked about the battery thing. Please ask a concrete question about your problem, rather than some hypothetical thoughts!

Comment: i still don't have a solution about battery notification, it caused of driver or my hardware i am still confuse.

Comment: Your other question is very vague to begin with. You might just have to wait, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only very few "drivers" not supported (or partially supported) by default: certain older wireless cards and AMD/Nvidia GPUs.
If you plan  on using 3d graphic then install the proprietary version of the driver from nvidia/AMD, and if your wifi doesn't work google it's model name for help. Other than these, there is no reason to worry about drivers in linux

Comment: is there any differences of performance if AMD display driver installed or not ?

Comment: There is an open source driver, that is installed by default. The proprietary one is needed to use 3d graphics.

Comment: The open-source driver should give you reasonable performance, except for heavy 3D graphics.

Comment: but I often found it hangs (all process stopped and i can't do nothing) on Ubuntu 11.10 when I run multiple processes

Comment: You need to tell up more about that. When you have those freezes, does Ctrl+Alt+F1 work? If it does, what is the output of the command top? What applications do you hae opened when the freeze happens?